# Combining multiple Unions Queries - is this the best way?

Tags: sql, select, union

I've got some SQL code working at the moment but I need to do another union. I want to ensure what I do is correct. Currently, this is what I have:

```
select * from (select * from stametadata
union select * from stajjmetadata)
```

I want to union on another table. Would this be correct?

```
select * from (select * from stametadata
union select * from stajjmetadata
union select * from staggmetadata)
```

Is this the neatest way to do it?

Comment: You don't need the nested select, using `select *` is ill advised and can only lead to unexpected errors, I would recommend you explicitely name your columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain `union`s. To be honest, you don't even need the outer query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM stametadata
UNION
SELECT * FROM stajjmetadata
UNION
SELECT * FROM staggmetadata
```

Comment: thank you, i don't know why i was told the outer `select` is necessary but apparently it was in this instance... could you see a reason why it would be?

Comment: basically is there any difference between your code and what i posted in terms of outcome? if not then i'd rather go with yours!

Comment: @caasswa if you aren't adding any logic in the outer query, it's pointless, and you can safely remove it

Comment: thank you :) i will do